# Page load using window.location in turbolinks-ios

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I am using [turbolinks-ios](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-ios) for builder ios app for my rails application. In my application, I am using `window.location` for loading particular page. On my ios application it is oping the browser instead of using app view. Does any one have idea how can I keep page loading on app view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Turoblinks.visit instead of window.location.

```
// window.location.href = url;
Turbolinks.visit(url);
```